# RuntimeException while inflating InputTextLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library

When i create new sample project with TextInputLayout , Its working good.

But in my exist project if i have added TextInputlayout , its throws runtime exception caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Why its happen? How to resolve this?

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textDialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why it happen? how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the gradle files of your sample project to your real project. Your project might not be setup correctly to use Material Design resources.